# java.io.FileNotFoundException when image file is inside jar using jxl.write.WritableImage

Tags: java, swing, embedded-resource, jxl

I am using WritableImage to write image into xls file, when I run it inside eclipse it is working fine. But when I run it in executable jar, I getting FileNotFoundException.

```
WritableImage image = new WritableImage(0.0D, 0.0D,
      1.0D, 3.0D,
      new File(getClass().getResource("/img/abouts.png").getPath()));
```

The image is indeed inside the jar. C:\scheduler-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar\img\abouts.png

Here's the exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:C:<some directory>scheduler-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/scheduler.jar!/img/abouts.png (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
    at jxl.biff.drawing.Drawing.getImageBytes(Drawing.java:778)
    at jxl.biff.drawing.BlipStoreEntry.<init>(BlipStoreEntry.java:98)
    at jxl.biff.drawing.DrawingGroup.write(DrawingGroup.java:427)
    at jxl.write.biff.WritableWorkbookImpl.write(WritableWorkbookImpl.java:931)
    at com.flagpole.client.IndividualCabinSched.<init>(IndividualCabinSched.java:218)
    at com.flagpole.client.Reports.getIndividualCabinScheReport(Reports.java:948)
    at com.flagpole.client.Reports.actionPerformed(Reports.java:652)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
```

Comment: A JAR entry is not a file. It is a resource. You can't persist in trying to turn its path into a filename. Use the URL returned by `getResource(),` or the `InputStream` returned by `getResourceAsStream()`, directly.

Answer (score 2):

Once the image is an a jar it is an [embedded-resource](/questions/tagged/embedded-resource) that will not be accessible by `File`.  Normally we would use a method call or constructor that accepts URL, but the API being used does not support that.

So instead you might use [`new WritableImage(double,double,double,double,byte[])`](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/write/WritableImage.html#WritableImage%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20byte%5B%5D%29) where the `byte[]` is the bytes of the image.

Comment: I tried that using this:
WritableImage image = new WritableImage(0.0D, 0.0D,
          1.0D, 3.0D,
          getClass().getResource("/img/abouts.png").getPath().getBytes());

or 
WritableImage image = new WritableImage(0.0D, 0.0D,
          1.0D, 3.0D,
          getClass().getResource("/img/abouts.png").getFile().getBytes());

but none is working

Comment: `<head-desk>`  Did you bother to try checking the size of the byte array from both methods?  Or (perish the thought) actually checking the documentation for the methods being used?  For example, [`getPath()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getPath--) returns a `String` and [`String.getBytes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes--)  *"Encodes this **`String`** into a sequence of bytes using the platform's default charset"*!  At the moment you are trying 'coding by magic' (putting random rubbish in code) which *never* works. ..

Comment: .. You need to go through the [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) lesson of the tutorial.